Intersections of intervals in lattices
In Bourbaki's Theory of Sets, Chapter III, § 1, 13 it is stated without proof that the intersection of intervals in an arbitrary lattice is again an interval, where they seem to define interval as a set of the form $[a, \infty), (-\infty,a], (a, \infty), (-\infty,a), (a,b), (a,b], [a,b), [a,b]$ (though they do not explicitly make this clear). In about half of the possible cases, this is straightforward to show.
However, does (for example) $(-\infty,a) \cap (-\infty,b)$ have to be an interval? It does not have to equal $(-\infty, \inf(a, b))$, as is the case in the lattice $\{\bot,a,b,\top\}, \bot \le a \le \top, \bot \le b \le \top$, where $(-\infty, \inf(a,b)) = (-\infty, \bot) = \emptyset$ but $(-\infty,a) = (-\infty,b) = \{\bot\}$. But this is still an interval and I cannot think of any case where it isn't.

There are three cases:

If $a \leq b$, then $(-\infty, a) \cap (-\infty, b) = (-\infty, a)$.
If $b \leq a$, then $(-\infty, a) \cap (-\infty, b) = (-\infty, b)$.
If $a$ and $b$ are incomparable, then $(-\infty, a) \cap (-\infty, b) = (-\infty, a \land b]$.


Right, because, indeed, if $a$ and $b$ are incomparable, then $a\wedge b<a,b$.
